# Separar contenido con String.Split() usando múltiples delimitadores en VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, regex, string

Estoy evaluando el contenido que obtengo de un TextBox. Lo que deseo hacer es usar la función `.Split` (o alguna otra función de no poder ser) para separar dicho contenido y almacenar cada parte en un vector.

```
Dim vectoraux() As String
vectoraux= TextBox1.Text.Split("<")
```

Es sencillo cuando es un solo carácter, incluso si quiero puedo evaluar varios al mismo tipo.

```
 Dim vectoraux() As String
 vectoraux= TextBox1.Text.Split("<>+-/*")
```

El problema viene cuando quiero evaluar una cadena, digamos que quisiera hacer esto.

```
 Dim vectoraux() As String
 vectoraux= TextBox1.Text.Split("<=,>=,>,<,+,-,/,*")
```

Sé que el codigo esta mal escrito, pero es simplemente para que entiendan lo que quiero hacer, la coma seria el separador de cada valor que deseo evaluar.
Creo que con el `.Split()` no se puede hacer esto, pero no estoy del todo seguro.

Me gustaría que me dijesen si hay alguna otra función similar que pueda utilizar, o alguna recomendación que se les ocurra. Esta es una pregunta para VB.NET 2010.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### 1. Con un array de elementos

La función [`String.Split(delimitadores(), opciones)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/tabh47cf(v=vs.110).aspx) acepta un array de delimitadores.

- En este caso es importante que `<=` y `>=` estén en el array de delimitadores antes que `>` y `<`, para que se separe correctamente.

**Código:**

```
Dim texto As String = "prueba+a-b<=c"

'Split con array de delimitadores
Dim delimitadores() As String = {"<=",">=",">","<","+","-","/","*"}
Dim vectoraux() As String
vectoraux = texto.Split(delimitadores,StringSplitOptions.None)

'mostrar resultado
For Each item As String In vectoraux
    Console.WriteLine("'{0}'", item)
Next
```

Resultado:

```
'prueba'
'a'
'b'
'c'
```

Demo:
http://rextester.com/IJBC7167

---

#### 2. Con regex

Para usar una sintaxis más "avanzada" en el split, se pueden usar [expresiones regulares](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx) (o regex), con la función [`Regex.Split(String)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ze12yx1d%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

El regex sería:

```
[-+/*]|[<>]=?
```

- Los corchetes definen una clase de caracteres (diferentes opciones para un mismo caracter).
- La barra vertical es un *OR* (alternancia).
- El `?` del final hace que el `=` sea opcional (abreviando a `<=|>=|[<>]`).

**Código:**

```
Imports System
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
```

```
Dim texto As String = "prueba+a-b<=c"

'Split con expresión regular
Dim regex As Regex = New Regex("[-+/*]|[<>]=?")
Dim vectoraux() As String
vectoraux = regex.Split(texto)

'mostrar resultado
For Each item As String In vectoraux
    Console.WriteLine("'{0}'", item)
Next
```

Resultado:

```
'prueba'
'a'
'b'
'c'
```

Demo:
http://rextester.com/VZPDC6661

---

#### 3. Con regex, pero incluyendo a los delimitadores

Además, las opciones con regex nos dan otras alternativas. Por ejemplo, si también queremos que aparezcan los delimitadores en el array, usamos un grupo (paréntesis):

```
([-+/*]|[<>]=?)
```

que nos devuelve el array:

```
{"prueba","+","a","-","b","<=","c"}
```

Demo: http://rextester.com/KDV25064